# Create a relationship between a PFUser and an Object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, ios8, pfuser

I have two classes in `Parse`

1. `User`
2. `WorkoutClasses`

The workout classes is a list of objects that describe a class the `PFUser` can subscribe to. 
How would I structure the data in swift so that in one view controller you, the 'Current User', can create a relation to that class, and then in another table view controller it will display the objects in the `WorkoutClasses` class that you have a relation to. 
Also, how would I delete the user relation with that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a parse relationship, from the `User` to the `WorkoutClasses` (though in parse that class should be called `WorkoutClass`).

In one VC you will display all `WorkoutClass`s and add items to the relationship. In the other VC you will query the relationship to display the items and you can remove from the relationship.